# Cocos2d: How to keep sprite instance visible during scene transition?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, transition, scene

I'm using cocos2d for the iphone and I want to have a sprite remain visible on the screen during a scene transition from one CCScene to the next. When using CCTransitionFade, for example, everything that is a child of the scene is faded out and then the next scene is faded in, but I want to keep the sprite visible and not fade with the rest of the scene. I'm guessing I have to add the sprite instance separate of the scene in order to get around the fading of the sprite, but I'm unsure of how to do this. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764579/how-to-add-global-cclayer-which-is-not-affected-by-scene-transitions-in-cocos2d

Comment: What are you trying to keep on screen - a logo?  You could add a UIImageView to the OpenGL view, and it will sit over the top of everything done in Cocos2D.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really retain objects/sprites in a CCScene if you are switching to another scene. It really depends on what the sprite is, will it respond to touch, does it animate, is it doing anything, etc, as to what the best approach is.

You can combine UIViews and Cocos views by adding a view to the viewcontroller in addition to the viewcontroller's view that is used by Cocos. That is the easiest way to persist images outside of Cocos transitions.